# String is not storing edittext value taken from user

Tags: android, string, android-fragments

I know it's so stupid to ask this question but I can't even find the error for the following to solve, I did everything as it should be still it won't store string value in the `String name` I  am implementing `EditText` in one of my `fragments` and storing the value in an `String` but the values won't store in the `String`. As per I know I have done everything correctly but this thing won't work at all.

In the `onCreateView` I am performing this code:

```
EditText av i= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.nameAndroid);
String name = avi.getText().toString();
```

And I am performing an operation where I check if the user has entered anything string based or not, then I will have it executed another part of code to do something with the entered `String` with this code below:

```
if(name.matches("")){
    Log.i(TAG, "input is empty");
} else{
    //code
}
```

But **everytime I am getting the log that the input is empty** and the string is not storing the value... I am not able to find the error here.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: if (speed.isEmpty()){...}else{...}

Comment: And you should put it for example in a button click because now it only happens in the oncreate.

Comment: no checking condition is working fine as i have already used the same in one of the activity class .... the problem that i am facing is that the string is not being stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too early to save the value of EditText in onCreateView - it's just created and user even didn't see it yet.

You have 2 ways:

a. If you have a button (user enters data and clicks a button), then add something like this in your `onClick` method:

```
    Editable e = yourEditText.getText();
    String string = "";
    if (e != null) string = e.toString();
```

b. If you do not have a button, you can add a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html):

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       Editable e = yourEditText.getText();
       String string = "";
       if (e != null) string = e.toString();
    }

    @Override    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
       }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
    }
    });
```

Note that you should save the value *after* user entered it - and onCreateView user even didn't see the view yet. In *a* case the user clicks the button - and though verifies that he entered something in the field. In *b* case we watch the changes in the field so the value is saved *only* if there is something to save.

You can save the value when user goes back/changes the screen, e.g. in onPause.

Comment: can't is just store the values directly as that of the activity as there we can do the steps in just a single line while thins will consume space

Comment: you can save the value in onPause then :)

Comment: can i do it in  onViewCreated?

Comment: No. In onViewCreated the views are only created and not even shown to user. It's called immediately after onCreateView but user didn't enter anything yet.

Comment: You should do it *after* user entered text.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are saving the empty EditText just after retrieve it. You have to add a listener on the EditText ot see when it is edited.

Use a TextWatcher : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
avi.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
      name= avi.getText().toString();
  }
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` of `EditText` gives you the content of the `EditText` at the time it is called, so you have to call `name= avi.getText().toString();` when this "operation" happens, not in `onCreateView` or it will only store the string value of the `EditText` *at that time*.

Comment: where do i call it then? in oncreateview i am calling the edittxt and taking the user inputs and assigning it to the string